# How can I make a TreeNode change the cursor when the mouse hovers over it?

Tags: vb.net, events, treeview, look-and-feel, treenode

I have created a menu using a treeview to launch forms when the user clicks on a node.  To complete the look-and-feel, I have set up the nodes to look like hyperlinks.  I'd like to have the cursor change to a hand (like the one you see when you hover over a link) when the user hovers over a node, however so far I've only been able to have the cursor change on hovering inside the treeview, as opposed to over a node.  As far as I can tell, a TreeNode doesn't have events such as MouseEnter, so I can't have them handle the events themselves.

I am attempting to use this function to loop through the nodes and check the Bounds property of the TreeNode against the Point property of the cursor, but so far the `If` block always evaluates to false, meaning that the cursor never changes.

```
Private Sub uxNavigationTreeView_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles uxNavigationTreeView.MouseHover
    For Each node As TreeNode In uxNavigationTreeView.Nodes
        For Each child As TreeNode In node.Nodes
            If child.Bounds.IntersectsWith(New Rectangle(Cursor.Position, New Size(1, 1))) Then
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction to accomplish this.  In essence, I am looking for the look-and-feel of a nested LinkButton array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MouseMove event.  Call the HitTest() method.

Comment: You have a control that doesn't raise the MouseMove event??  Abandon all hope.

Comment: Sorry, was using the wrong MouseMove event.  That worked really well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor.Position returns the mouse pointer position in screen coordinates - use uxNavigationTreeView.[PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) to convert the position to client coordinates and I think you'll then have more luck.

Comment: I'll give that a shot tomorrow.  Off work for the day.  Thanks.